# Get the values from a Pivot Table row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a pivot table that shows sales per year. The rows contain year and values are the sum of the sales.
Is there a formula, not code, to return the list of years from the pivot table.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your pivot table? AFAK, there is a [GETPIVOTDATA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/getpivotdata-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), but it does not seem to achieve your requirenments. _I suggest you copy the region of years in Pivot Table to a new region and keep value only_. If needed you may try to use formula to handle these data.

Comment: The pivot table is simply a list of years with a filter, so you could have one year showing or multiple years. If I set a range and use TextJoin it works, but if the pivot table exceeds the range the formula doesn't capture all the years, that's why I am looking for a way to reference the columns.